# Is there a difference between connecting to a Wi-Fi router and connecting to a hotspot?

Tags: wifi, tethering

I use an old MacBook Pro (sorry I don't have the model/specs to hand!) for doing audio/visuals for church services. The place we're in doesn't have Wi-Fi so we hotspot off a phone to connect to the internet. Sometimes the mac has issues connecting to the phone hotspot (it doesn't appear to be an issue with the phone because other devices are able to connect to the hotspot).

Last week it was particularly bad so the person on AV ended up going to a local guy's house to use their Wi-Fi. From what I gather the Mac didn't have any issues connecting to the Wi-Fi.

I would have thought that there was no difference from the perspective of the Mac (or any connecting device) between a phone hotspot and a Wi-Fi router and that it was simple happenstance that the Mac successfully connected to the Wi-Fi router. Am I wrong?

The church leader now wants to get a pop-up Wi-Fi device so we don't have these problems in the future, but I'm worried it might be a waste of money. My guess is that there was some error in one of the drivers and a machine restart should solve the issue in most cases.

Comment: You didn't indicate that you'd restarted the Mac before connecting, or restarted the Mac after the initial connection didn't work. I suggest that when this happens again, restart all the devices involved.

Comment: Hey yeah I would have told them to restart devices, but I wasn't there at the time and wasn't contacted. I asked the guy who was on AV whether he tried restarting and he said he didn't. As I said above, because it successfully connected to a Wi-Fi router now people think that getting Wi-Fi is the solution.

Comment: Wi-Fi has a number of version levels. Devices are supposed to negotiate to the highest version that they both support, but sometimes there can be compatibility problems.

Comment: Since this is intermittent, it sounds like one of the devices has a flaky antenna, and the other one is too sensitive to this. If you can reproduce the problem with other devices, it may be hard to pin it down.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @Barmer, it's intermittent so perhaps it is a flaky antenna. I think when it does play up it then struggles to pair to a number of devices. Equally the Mac is running an older OS so it might also be behind on Wi-Fi versions.